# Trouble importing project in lerna

Tags: lerna

I'm trying to import my first project into a lerna repo and getting the following error:

```
lerna ERR! import Rolling back to previous HEAD (commit a235ee9b3c382c9751abf792a22b2ec9df894a18)
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Failed to apply commit a932c8cf8.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Command failed: git am -3 --keep-non-patch
lerna ERR! EIMPORT error: Failed to merge in the changes.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Applying: Made Device Analytics Controller. Made device-analytics.stache be rendered through controller.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Using index info to reconstruct a base tree...
lerna ERR! EIMPORT M    packages/some-repo/app/scripts/app/controls/active-device.js
lerna ERR! EIMPORT M    packages/some-repo/app/templates/device/active-device.stache
lerna ERR! EIMPORT M    packages/some-repo/views/index.jade
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Auto-merging packages/some-repo/app/templates/device/device-analytics.stache
lerna ERR! EIMPORT CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in packages/some-repo/app/templates/device/device-analytics.stache
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Auto-merging packages/some-repo/app/scripts/app/controls/device-analytics.js
lerna ERR! EIMPORT CONFLICT (add/add): Merge conflict in packages/some-repo/app/scripts/app/controls/device-analytics.js
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Auto-merging packages/some-repo/app/scripts/app/controls/active-device.js
lerna ERR! EIMPORT CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in packages/some-repo/app/scripts/app/controls/active-device.js
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Patch failed at 0001 Made Device Analytics Controller. Made device-analytics.stache be rendered through controller.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
lerna ERR! EIMPORT When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
lerna ERR! EIMPORT If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
lerna ERR! EIMPORT
lerna ERR! EIMPORT
lerna ERR! EIMPORT You may try again with --flatten to import flat history.
```

If I run the import command with the `flatten` flag, I get this error:

```
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Failed to apply commit f16ede066.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Command failed: git am -3 --keep-non-patch
lerna ERR! EIMPORT error: git diff header lacks filename information when removing 1 leading pathname component (line 845968)
lerna ERR! EIMPORT error: could not build fake ancestor
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Applying: Adding dist files. Refs #17
lerna ERR! EIMPORT Patch failed at 0001 Adding dist files. Refs #17
lerna ERR! EIMPORT The copy of the patch that failed is found in: .git/rebase-apply/patch
lerna ERR! EIMPORT When you have resolved this problem, run "git am --continue".
lerna ERR! EIMPORT If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git am --skip" instead.
lerna ERR! EIMPORT To restore the original branch and stop patching, run "git am --abort".
```

I also posted an issue on their github repo: https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/1644

What should I be looking for?

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 4):

I've fixed the bug in this PR - only resolves it for `lerna import --flatten <dir>`:

https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/2037

Essentially the colorized output of `git log` was leading to this error.

If you need this for your project and the PR is not yet merged (or if it is, maybe you should upgrade lerna), you can checkout lerna then make the changes in the file shown in the PR, then run `npm link` so you can execute the modified version in the CLI, then finally:

```
lerna import --flatten <dir>
```

And, remember to `npm unlink` lerna when you're done.